Make a column with conditional values that reflect the max value in a third column
I am trying to add a column to a dataframe based on a complex conditional, and I can't find any posts that quite match what I'm trying to do.  I have data of the following type, with three categorical columns ("trial", "word", "point") and one continuous column ("value"):
    trial  word  point value
1  trial1 word1 point1   337
2  trial1 word1 point2   105
3  trial1 word1 point3   289
4  trial1 word1 point4   190
5  trial1 word2 point1   167
6  trial1 word2 point2   223
7  trial1 word2 point3   384
8  trial1 word2 point4   143
9  trial2 word1 point1   179
10 trial2 word1 point2   101
11 trial2 word1 point3   122
12 trial2 word1 point4   213
13 trial2 word3 point1   409
14 trial2 word3 point2   221
15 trial2 word3 point3   582
16 trial2 word3 point4   178

What I want to know is for a given trial, for a given word, which point corresponds to the highest value?  And then I want to copy that point label into a new column, for each of the rows for that word.  This is what the new column (max_point) should look like:
    trial  word  point value max_point
1  trial1 word1 point1   337    point1
2  trial1 word1 point2   105    point1
3  trial1 word1 point3   289    point1
4  trial1 word1 point4   190    point1
5  trial1 word2 point1   167    point3
6  trial1 word2 point2   223    point3
7  trial1 word2 point3   384    point3
8  trial1 word2 point4   143    point3
9  trial2 word1 point1   179    point4
10 trial2 word1 point2   101    point4
11 trial2 word1 point3   122    point4
12 trial2 word1 point4   213    point4
13 trial2 word3 point1   409    point3
14 trial2 word3 point2   221    point3
15 trial2 word3 point3   582    point3
16 trial2 word3 point4   178    point3

To restate, max_point represents which point has the highest value in a given word in a given trial.  So for instance, in trial1 word1 (first 4 rows), of the 4 points, point1 has the highest value (337), so max_point has the label "point1" for each of the 4 rows for that word.
Some posts ask how to print a max value into a new column based on a conditional, but not how to print a categorical label corresponding to the max value.  How might I go about this?
Please let me know if I can offer any clarification, and thank you!

With data.table:
library(data.table)

dt[,max_point := point[which.max(value)], .(trial, word)][]
#>      trial   word  point value max_point
#>     <char> <char> <char> <int>    <char>
#>  1: trial1  word1 point1   337    point1
#>  2: trial1  word1 point2   105    point1
#>  3: trial1  word1 point3   289    point1
#>  4: trial1  word1 point4   190    point1
#>  5: trial1  word2 point1   167    point3
#>  6: trial1  word2 point2   223    point3
#>  7: trial1  word2 point3   384    point3
#>  8: trial1  word2 point4   143    point3
#>  9: trial2  word1 point1   179    point4
#> 10: trial2  word1 point2   101    point4
#> 11: trial2  word1 point3   122    point4
#> 12: trial2  word1 point4   213    point4
#> 13: trial2  word3 point1   409    point3
#> 14: trial2  word3 point2   221    point3
#> 15: trial2  word3 point3   582    point3
#> 16: trial2  word3 point4   178    point3

Data:
dt <- fread(input = "id    trial  word  point value
            1  trial1 word1 point1   337
            2  trial1 word1 point2   105
            3  trial1 word1 point3   289
            4  trial1 word1 point4   190
            5  trial1 word2 point1   167
            6  trial1 word2 point2   223
            7  trial1 word2 point3   384
            8  trial1 word2 point4   143
            9  trial2 word1 point1   179
            10 trial2 word1 point2   101
            11 trial2 word1 point3   122
            12 trial2 word1 point4   213
            13 trial2 word3 point1   409
            14 trial2 word3 point2   221
            15 trial2 word3 point3   582
            16 trial2 word3 point4   178")[,id := NULL]


With dplyr
library(dplyr)


df |>
  mutate(max_point = point[which.max(value)],
         .by = c(trial, word))
#> # A tibble: 16 × 5
#>    trial  word  point  value max_point
#>    <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <int> <chr>    
#>  1 trial1 word1 point1   337 point1   
#>  2 trial1 word1 point2   105 point1   
#>  3 trial1 word1 point3   289 point1   
#>  4 trial1 word1 point4   190 point1   
#>  5 trial1 word2 point1   167 point3   
#>  6 trial1 word2 point2   223 point3   
#>  7 trial1 word2 point3   384 point3   
#>  8 trial1 word2 point4   143 point3   
#>  9 trial2 word1 point1   179 point4   
#> 10 trial2 word1 point2   101 point4   
#> 11 trial2 word1 point3   122 point4   
#> 12 trial2 word1 point4   213 point4   
#> 13 trial2 word3 point1   409 point3   
#> 14 trial2 word3 point2   221 point3   
#> 15 trial2 word3 point3   582 point3   
#> 16 trial2 word3 point4   178 point3

Data
df <- structure(list(trial = c("trial1", "trial1", "trial1", "trial1", 
                               "trial1", "trial1", "trial1", "trial1", "trial2", "trial2", "trial2", 
                               "trial2", "trial2", "trial2", "trial2", "trial2"), word = c("word1", 
                                                                                           "word1", "word1", "word1", "word2", "word2", "word2", "word2", 
                                                                                           "word1", "word1", "word1", "word1", "word3", "word3", "word3", 
                                                                                           "word3"), point = c("point1", "point2", "point3", "point4", "point1", 
                                                                                                               "point2", "point3", "point4", "point1", "point2", "point3", "point4", 
                                                                                                               "point1", "point2", "point3", "point4"), value = c(337L, 105L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  289L, 190L, 167L, 223L, 384L, 143L, 179L, 101L, 122L, 213L, 409L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  221L, 582L, 178L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              -16L))


Base R. A classical split-*apply-combine approach.

split() and lapply():

lapply(split(df0, ~trial+word, drop = TRUE), 
       transform, max_point = point[which.max(value)]) 


combine

either with do.call("rbind", ...) (base)
split(df0, ~trial+word, drop = TRUE) |>
  lapply(transform, max_point = point[which.max(value)]) |>
  do.call(what = "rbind") |>
  `rownames<-`(NULL) # cosmetics 

or unlist2d() from {collapse}
split(df0, ~trial+word, drop = TRUE) |>
  lapply(transform, max_point = point[which.max(value)]) |>
  collapse::unlist2d(idcols = FALSE)

both giving
    trial  word  point value max_point
1  trial1 word1 point1   337    point1
2  trial1 word1 point2   105    point1
3  trial1 word1 point3   289    point1
4  trial1 word1 point4   190    point1
5  trial2 word1 point1   179    point4
6  trial2 word1 point2   101    point4
7  trial2 word1 point3   122    point4
8  trial2 word1 point4   213    point4
9  trial1 word2 point1   167    point3
10 trial1 word2 point2   223    point3
11 trial1 word2 point3   384    point3
12 trial1 word2 point4   143    point3
13 trial2 word3 point1   409    point3
14 trial2 word3 point2   221    point3
15 trial2 word3 point3   582    point3
16 trial2 word3 point4   178    point3


Note
Advantage: (1) incredible fast; (2) idcols is a pleasant argument.
Disadvantage: external library.
